# How can I wrap an interactive R learnr tutorial in a package?

Tags: r, r-package, learnr

I’m new to creating learnr tutorials and even more to creating packages, but after reading tutorials on these two topics, I can now create simple packages and simple learnr tutorials. Now that I know a bit about both topics, I would like to deploy my interactive tutorials in a basic package, but there are not many resources available. Can you show me how to do this in the simplest possible way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to:

1. Create a package
2. Use a tutorial inside that package

### 1. Create a package

Check the chapter 2 of [R Packages](https://r-pkgs.org/whole-game.html) by Hadley Wickham. You'll understand how to start one by using:

```r
library(devtools)

create_package("path/to/package")
```

### 2. Use a tutorial inside that package

Once you started a package you'll need to create a tutorial inside the `inst` directory of your package. [`use_tutorial()`](https://usethis.r-lib.org/reference/use_tutorial.html) does it for you. Be sure to be in the package project inside RStudio.

```r
usethis::use_tutorial(name, title)
```

That's all. Be sure to check the `learnr` [documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/learnr/index.html) for more details. More steps in https://education.rstudio.com/blog/2020/09/delivering-learnr-tutorials-in-a-package/

Comment: Your help was valuable, thank you. I created my first ready to use and share learnr tutorial. Do you know how to costumize the html/css of the tutorial?

Comment: Yeah. Check the section for External resources in the learnr documentation. Don't forget to accept the answer here

Comment: I have  found an awsome tutorial done by **ALLISON HORST** here [link](https://allisonhorst.shinyapps.io/dplyr-learnr/)